# Mobile browser download file: not working

Tags: java, download, mobile-browser

On mobile browser, How to save a file from a web page? For example, save a picture into camera folder.

I set response header:

```
response.setContentType(contentType);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Foo");
```

It works on desktop browser. But nothing happens on mobile browser(safari, chrome on Iphone).
Thanks for help.